# Office Online Server and SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, office-online-server

We have configured 2 server in office online farm and connected to SharePoint.

How to check which Office Online server my request is hitting?

Comment: Did you set up a loadbalancer in front of those two OOS-Servers?

Comment: Yes, we have app gateways in azure since our servers are in azure. We want to check if any server become unhealthy and then to take the server out. For this purpose, we are trying to programmatically hit /_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx service in OOS in C# or powershell, but I am unable to find how to programmatically use the OOS service . 

\n

Any other ways to check if OOS service is healthy or Any ways to programmatic requests to OOS service?